# Infinite Scroll On Custom Page Magento

Tags: magento, infinite-scroll

I have installed `Strategery InfiniteScroll`. Which is working great for category listing page. Now i have a `custom product page`. I want to apply Strategery InfiniteScroll on my custom product page. How to do.?

My Page

```
<?php

 $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'featured','eq'=>'1')));
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$_productCollection->getSelect()->limit(20);

?>
  //loop for products
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, assure you have included .js file in your custom page.
if you see the ias.phtml template, it has some container defined.
You need to add the same code for your custom page.

For documentation of infinite ajax scroll, read [this](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: Then where you want to add ? do you have any link for that ?

Comment: i have a new.phtml file.. which i am loading on home page. the code is above for fetching products. so is there any to load products on scroll.?\

Comment: So, why you need ias ?

Comment: now i need any of scroll which load my custom products not paged products. any idea.?